# how do i call bitmap compress function in my code

Tags: android

how do i compres image so is save big image i found code but what i write in  R.drawable.my?

my code save capture image in this line

```
 //this line yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");

@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

            if (imageReturnedIntent.getExtras() != null) {
                // here is the image from camera



                yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap)  
   imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");



                ByteArrayOutputStream outStr = new  
    ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,  
   outStr);
                blob = outStr.toByteArray();
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);

            }
```

i found this code how do i call this in my code?? my code is above this decode code

```
  image =decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my, 100, 100);



    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
     imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

 // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
 final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

 // Calculate inSampleSize
 options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
 return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
  }

   public static int calculateInSampleSize(
    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
  final int height = options.outHeight;
  final int width = options.outWidth;
 int inSampleSize = 1;

  if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

// Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

// Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
// a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
// requested height and width.
inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

  return inSampleSize;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Use Below Code to Compress your Bitmap and save it

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); //here you will get your Bitmap
selectedImagePath = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".jpg"; //make random name for your compressed image
Log.i("TAG", "New selectedImagePath before file "+ selectedImagePath);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), selectedImagePath);
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry, Camera Crashed-Please Report as Crash A.",3).show();
   }

  selectedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + selectedImagePath;
  Log.i("TAG", "After File Created  " + selectedImagePath);
  Bitmap bm = decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
  mImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Hope it will Help.

Comment: what i wirte in file  path? File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), selectedImagePath);

Comment: i have this code
  final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
              File photos = new File(imageFilePath);
              yourSelectedImage = decodeFile(photos);
how can i give  decodeFile funtion to capture image path??

Comment: @hayyaanam : then you no need to go ahead. just write line 'photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);' and then set your bitmap in imageview. i have done this code thinking might you want to save a separate file after compressing.

Comment: please comment on my new post i decrible my  problem there clearly